# ESP32 Fails on set wifi Hostname

Tags: esp32

I am using the AT command binary (provided by Espresif) to interface my wi-fi application. In order to identify the device over a network, I've changed the Hostname to a known name, but when I scan the network, the Hostname still being "Espressif", instead of being my "Own Hostname".

Does anyone knows how to fix that? I actually think that it's an error on AT command's binary.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue.

Code looks like:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "WiFi.h"

void setup() {
    // Start the Wifi connection ...
    WiFi.enableSTA(true);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    // TODO Hostname setting does not work. Always shows up as "espressif"
    if(WiFi.setHostname("myHostname")) {
        Serial.printf("\nHostname set!\n");
    } else {
        Serial.printf("\nHostname NOT set!\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not saying its ok, I think it's pretty crappy, just confirming your issue. Its the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

After literally more than 10 hours of research, trying to pinpoint, analyze and/or fix the issue one way or another, I gave up and accepted the workaround. You can find it [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2537#issuecomment-508558849).

In short, what I do and what works for me is:

```
WiFi.disconnect();
WiFi.config(INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE);  // This is a MUST!
if (!WiFi.setHostname("myFancyESP32")) {
  Serial.println("Hostname failed to configure");
}
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
```

This is really frustrating but for the time being it seems that the issue comes from the ESP IDF and unless it is fixed there, it will not work.

Comment: Any updates on this ? Because this workaround doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the Espressif code. The workaround is to reset the WIFI *before* setting hostname and starting the WIFI:

```
WiFi.disconnect(true);
WiFi.config(INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE, INADDR_NONE);     
WiFi.setHostname(hostname);
```

Also note that the OTA may make the issue even harder to fix. If using MDSN and OTA, please add the following code (after the WIFI-stuff) to ensure that the hostname gets correlcty set:

```
MDNS.begin(hostname);
ArduinoOTA.setHostname(hostname);
ArduinoOTA.begin();
```

For details, please read the [issue 2537](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/issues/2537) in the Espressif GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wait for Wifi to set-up. easiest (never the best) way with Delay(150).